# perl regex replace only part of string

Tags: regex, perl

I need to write a perl regex to convert

```
site.company.com => dc=site,dc=company,dc=com
```

Unfortunately I am not able to remove the trailing "," using the regex I came with below. I could of course remove the trailing "," in the next statement but would prefer that to be handled as a part of the regex.

```
$data="site.company.com";
$data =~ s/([^.]+)\.?/dc=$1,/g;
print $data;
```

This above code prints:

```
dc=site,dc=company,dc=com,
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"This above code prints: dc=site,dc=company,dc=com,"_ That's exactly what you want, isn't it?

Comment: "dc=site,dc=company,dc=com"  - Without the trailing ','

Comment: Ooh yeah sorry, overlooked that.

Comment: You can add one more line after your code `chop($data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data =~s/\./,dc=/g&&s/^/dc=/g;
```

tested below:

```
> echo "site.company.com" | perl -pe 's/\./,dc=/g&&s/^/dc=/g'
dc=site,dc=company,dc=com
```

Comment: Ah. +1 for Multiple substitution. My question is theoretical in the sense that I am looking to achieve this with a single regex statement and without using sed style substitution.

Comment: `$data =~s/\./,dc=/g&&s/^/dc=/g;` -- the first substitution will be applied to `$data`, but the second to `$_`.

Comment: But how does it matter when the final out come is what that is required?And @TLP i like your solution.

Comment: @sarathi The final outcome is not what is required. You perform the two substitutions on different variables in your first example. The second example is *not* the same as the first. Thank you. It seems the OP wanted a regex solution, though.

Answer (score 4):

When handling urls it may be a good idea to use a module such as `URI`. However, I do not think it applies in this case.

This task is most easily solved with a split and join, I think:

```
my $url = "site.company.com";
my $string = join ",",            # join the parts with comma
             map "dc=$_",         # add the dc= to each part
             split /\./, $url;    # split into parts
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
my $x = "site.company.com";
my @a = split /\./, $x;
map { s/^/dc=/; } @a;
print join",", @a;
```

Answer (score 0):

just put like this,

```
$data="site.company.com";
$data =~ s/,dc=$1/dc=$1/g; #(or) $data =~ s/,dc/dc/g;
print $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try the `/ge` route:

```
$data =~ s{^|(\.)}{
    ( $1 && ',' ) . 'dc='
}ge;
```

e = evaluate replacement as Perl code.

So, it says given the start of the string, or a dot, make the following replacement. If it captured a period, then emit a `','`. Regardless of this result, insert `'dc='`.

Note, that I like to use a brace style of delimiter on all my evaluated replacements.